# Href and confirm button

Tags: javascript, jquery

have a href as follows:

```
<a class="eLink" href="http:www.abc.com">chk here xyz</a></li>
```

and javascript for "eLink" is as follows:

```
    $("a.eLink").click(function link(evt) {
        url = evt.target.href;

        if (url.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(".gov") <= 0) {

            var tk = "Do you really want to continue?";

            if (confirm(tk)) {
                window.open(url, 'newwin');
            }else{
               window.open(url,'_self'); 
            }
        }
        else
        { window.open(url, 'newwin'); }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Now my issue is when i click the href and click 'cancel' in the confirm button, my page goes to "abc.com", but it shouldnt happen. My browser should remain the same. what script should i use in the else part so i remain the same page. thanks.

Comment: I indented your HTML and JS code so that it showed up with proper formatting. For future reference, it's a simple as indenting the code with 4 spaces, or highlighting it and clicking the **`{ }`** button.

Comment: I see you've added the jQuery tag. Perhaps you should consider utilizing the jQuery UI dialog instead of the icky standard confirm box?

Comment: Im not to sure what you mean with "remain the same", is it that you dont want to leave the page or you just want the link work as normal?

Comment: Your else is a window.open. If you dont want them to go anywhere just leave it blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the else out.

```
if (confirm(tk)) {
    window.open(url, 'newwin');
  }
```

Sidenote, IE8 and lower doesn't implement the `indexOf` function so you may want to patch it by writing your own implementation.

Comment: nope didnt help. I think the <a href> shdnt point to abc.com..not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @javaiText, can you post a jsFiddle in which this didn't work?  I duplicated what IC did and it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/WJa2D/

Comment: @javaiText: Check your console for errors. I'm guessing you're getting an error, and the JS isn't working at all.

Comment: @amnotiam, that's a good point.  He does have an extra `});` in his pasted code.

Comment: That's probably from the `document.ready` xyan ewing, plus he says that he sees the alert, so i'm guessing no errors ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: Very true. That rules that out.

Answer (score 1):

the default action should already be prevented by `return false;` (jQuery style)

the problem is that if you click cancel `window.open(url,'_self');` is executed, just remove the else part of the confirm condition

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRQzy/)

Comment: removing that else part didnt help

Comment: -1 `return false;` does not work as you describe but `evt.preventDefault();`

Comment: [javaiText](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1071967/javaitext) check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRQzy/)

Comment: [iambriansreed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/144665/iambriansreed) according to jQuery documentation: Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault(). A false value can also be passed for the handler as a shorthand for function(){ return false; }. So, $("a.disabled").on("click", false); attaches an event handler to all links with class "disabled" that prevents them from being followed when they are clicked and also stops the event from bubbling.... would be glad if you could remove the -1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
var tk = "Do you really want to continue?";

            if (confirm(tk)) {
                window.open(url, 'newwin');
            }else{
               window.open(url,'_self'); 
            }
```

This means that if they click cancel, `False` will be returned, which will still open the link. You need to remove `window.open` in your `else` statement

```
if (confirm(tk)) {
                    window.open(url, 'newwin');
                }
```